# use react key to access form data in a list

Tags: reactjs

I've a table that has two form elements in it and I'm trying to get the data out of one of the elements, however I'm uncertain as to how to access the input field correctly.

My thought is that I should be able to access all elements using the key prop however I've yet to see this in use and I'm now not certain its possible.

What I have is the following which generates table rows for a table which includes a checkbox and a select list:

```
var rows = []    
rows = filteredItems.map(
(item, index) => 
   <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td><Select2 data={['', 'feature', 'documents', 'discussion']}/</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value={item.id} onChange={() => this.updateService(index, item.id)}/></td>                
    </tr>
);
```

on my `onChangeEvent` I can get the key and the `checkbox` value, but I'm at a loss as to how to get the value of the select.

As per request I'm including my react component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as Bootstrap from "react-bootstrap";

import Select2 from 'react-select2-wrapper';
import 'react-select2-wrapper/css/select2.css';

import $ from "jquery";
import _ from "lodash";

import Layout from "../ui/layout";
import TitleBar from "../ui/title-bar";

export default class Services extends Component {

    state = {
        pageSize: 25,
        page: 1,
        items: [],
        orderBy: "",
        sortBy: "",
        query: ""
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        $.get("http://localhost:5000/_api/admin/services", result => this.setState({items: result}));
    }

    isActiveButton(page){
        var activePage = this.state.page;
        return `paginate_button ${page === activePage ? "active" : ""}`;
    }

    isLastPage(){
        var numberOfButtons = Math.ceil(this.state.items.length / this.state.pageSize);
        return `paginate_button next ${this.state.page === numberOfButtons ? "disabled" : "" }`; 
    }

    isFirstPage(){
        return `paginate_button next ${this.state.page === 1 ? "disabled" : "" }`;
    }

    orderById = () => {
        var sortBy = this.state.sortBy === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        this.setState({orderBy: "id", sortBy: sortBy});
    }

    orderByName = () => { 
        var sortBy = this.state.sortBy === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        this.setState({orderBy: "name", sortBy: sortBy}); 
    }

    search= () => { 
        this.setState({query: this.refs.search.value});
    }

    updatePage = (page, direction) => {
        if(direction){
            var numberOfButtons = Math.ceil(this.state.items.length / this.state.pageSize);
            if(direction === "next" && page <= numberOfButtons)
            {
                this.setState({page: page});
            }

            if(direction === "prev" && page > 0)
            {
                this.setState({page: page});
            }
        } else {
            this.setState({page: page});
        }
    }

    updateService = (e) => {
        var serviceId = e.target.value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "http://localhost:5000/_api/admin/monitor/service",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: serviceId }),
            dataType: "json"
            });
    }

    render(){
        var rows = [];

        var filteredItems = [];
        var items = this.state.items;

        var orderBy = this.state.orderBy;
        var sortBy = this.state.sortBy;

        var pageSize = this.state.pageSize;
        var currentPage = this.state.page - 1;

        var query = this.state.query;

        filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query));

        filteredItems = _.orderBy(filteredItems, function(item){
            return typeof item[orderBy] === "string" ? item[orderBy] : item[orderBy];
        }, sortBy);

        var numberOfButtons = Math.ceil(filteredItems.length / pageSize);
        var numberOfelements = filteredItems.length;

        var start = currentPage * pageSize;
        var end = start + pageSize;
        filteredItems = filteredItems.slice(start, end);

        rows = filteredItems.map((item, index) => 
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td><Select2 data={['', 'feature', 'documents', 'discussion']}/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value={item.id} checked={item.isMonitored} onChange={this.updateService}/></td>                
            </tr>
        );

        //-- setup the pager
        var buttons = _.range(1, numberOfButtons + 1).map(idx =>
        <li key={idx} className={this.isActiveButton(idx)}>
            <a href="#" onClick={() => this.updatePage(idx, null)}>{idx}</a>
        </li>
        )

        return(
            <span>
                <Layout>
                    <TitleBar
                        title="Jolera Alerts Board Settings"
                        details="Select the services to monitor"
                        root="Settings"
                        page="Services"
                        url="/settings"/>

                        <Bootstrap.Row>
                        <Bootstrap.Col md={2}>
                            <div className="hpanel hjolera">
                                <div className="panel-body">
                                    <div className="m-b-md">
                                        <h4>Settings</h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <Bootstrap.Button id="refresh" bsStyle="info" block className="btn-jolera">Update Services</Bootstrap.Button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Bootstrap.Col>
                        <Bootstrap.Col md={10}>
                            <div className="hpanel hjolera">
                                < div className="panel-body">
                                    <div className="table-responsive">
                                        <Bootstrap.Row>
                                            <Bootstrap.Col md={6}></Bootstrap.Col>
                                            <Bootstrap.Col md={6}>
                                                    <div className="form-group">
                                                        <div>
                                                        <label  style={{top: 8}} className="col-md-2 control-label">Search</label>
                                                        <div className="col-sm-10"><input id="search" ref="search" type="text" className="form-control" onChange={() => this.search()}/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                            </Bootstrap.Col>
                                        </Bootstrap.Row>
                                        <table
                                            className="table table-condensed table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th onClick={this.orderById}>Id</th>
                                                    <th onClick={this.orderByName}>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Severity</th>
                                                    <th>Monitor</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {rows}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="panel-footer">
                                <Bootstrap.Row>
                                    <Bootstrap.Col md={4}>
                                        Showing {start} to {end} of {numberOfelements} entries
                                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                                    <Bootstrap.Col md={8} > 
                                        <ul className="pagination pull-right" style={{margin: 0}}>
                                            <li className={this.isFirstPage()}>
                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => this.updatePage(this.state.page - 1, "prev")}>Previous</a>
                                            </li>
                                            {buttons}
                                            <li className={this.isLastPage()}>
                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => this.updatePage(this.state.page + 1, "next")}>Next</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                                </Bootstrap.Row>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Bootstrap.Col>
                    </Bootstrap.Row>

                </Layout>
            </span>
        );
    }

}
```

The issue that I'm having is that if I click on a `checkbox` I want to capture the whole row and get the value of both the checkbox and the select list, but currently I can't seem to get it. Right now as I have my code I have it set for the checkbox to only listen to the `onClick` event and from there I can get my checkbox value, but I also want to get my select list value if one exists.

Comment: do you have a whole sample of code? it still unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using react-selec2-wrapper for that? YOu should provide to Select2 two properties, value and onChange where onChange will set up a value and vlaue will keep it.